# Is it wrong to navigate to a view from 2 different parents in the navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Lets say I have 2 parent views in the navigation controller, A and B. A is a list of libraries that when you press on a library it takes you to a view with that library's information (lets call this view C). B is where the user can search for books, and a few levels deeper into B the user can see libraries that hold this book, so here is also a button to pop view C to view library information. Is it acceptable to do this? Maybe I will run into problems doing this? The other option is to duplicate the view but I don't think that is right either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing a single view controller is not only *acceptable*, but it is also *highly desirable*. If you can make it so that the same visual setup and code can be used in two different situations, perhaps with the different context coming in, you should definitely prefer that to duplicating the view.

The advantage of this approach is that you get better maintainability. Any time that you need to change a view with a duplicate, you must remember to make the same change in two places. A single view does not create such maintenance liability.

All you need to do is providing a way for your single view controller to decide which libraries need to be shown. You can do this by setting the list of libraries into the model prior to navigating to the library view, or by providing a filter to the view controller to choose the libraries that it needs to display.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept the answer in 4 minutes (when it lets me)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, C is a detail view, so there's nothing wrong if you want to show it from different places.